# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'selectedIndex')

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, select, codeigniter-3

Why does i can't get the select index of my select? the output is always undefined and sometimes 0 why does i cannot get the select? if i use this one

```
var index = document.getElementById("#product_"+row_id).selectedIndex;
```

its giving me an error of

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'selectedIndex')

what seems the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".select_group").select2();
   $("#OrderMainNav").addClass('active');
   $("#createOrderSubMenu").addClass('active');

var btnCust = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add picture tags" ' + 
    'onclick="alert(\'Call your custom code here.\')">' +
    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i>' +
    '</button>'; 

// Add new row in the table 
$("#add_row").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: base_url + '/orders/getTableProductRow/',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(response) {
          var table = $("#product_info_table");
          var count_table_tbody_tr = $("#product_info_table tbody tr").length;
          var row_id = count_table_tbody_tr + 1;    
                         var html = '<tr id="row_'+row_id+'">'+
               '<td>'+ 
                '<select class="form-control select_group product update-select" data-row-id="'+row_id+'" id="product_'+row_id+'" name="product[]" style="width:100%;" onchange="getProductData('+row_id+')">'+
                    '<option selected>--Select Products--</option>';
                    $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                      html += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';             
                    });
                    
                  html += '</select>'+
                '</td>'+ 
                 '<td><input placeholder="Available Qty" type="text" name="availqty1[]" id="availqty_'+row_id+'" class="form-control" disabled><input type="hidden" name="availqty_value1[]" id="availqty_value_'+row_id+'" class="form-control"></td>'+
                '<td><input placeholder="Quantity" type="number" name="qty[]" id="qty_'+row_id+'" class="form-control" onclick="getTotal('+row_id+')" onkeyup="getTotal('+row_id+')"></td>'+
                '<td><input placeholder="Rate" type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate_'+row_id+'" class="form-control" disabled><input type="hidden" name="rate_value[]" id="rate_value_'+row_id+'" class="form-control"></td>'+
                '<td><input placeholder="Amount" type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_'+row_id+'" class="form-control" disabled><input type="hidden" name="amount_value[]" id="amount_value_'+row_id+'" class="form-control"></td>'+
                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeRow(\''+row_id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>'+
                '</tr>';

        

            if(count_table_tbody_tr >= 1) {
            $("#product_info_table tbody tr:last").after(html);  

          }
          else {
            $("#product_info_table tbody").html(html);
          }

          $(".product").select2();
          //console.log(info);
          //console.log(index);
          //var index = document.getElementById("#product_"+row_id).selectedIndex;
          //var index = $("#product_"+row_id).get(0).selectedIndex;
          //var product_id = $("#product_"+row_id).val(); 
         // var value = $('.update-select').selectedIndex;
          //console.log(value);
          

         //HERE I CAN'T GET THE INDEX SO I PUT 2 WHAT IS THE CORRECT WAY TO GET THE INDEX?
          $('#product_'+row_id+' option:eq(' + 2 + ')').remove();

      }
    });

  return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Would seem to be suggesting that `getElementById("#product_"+row_id)` is returning null (does it actaully exist) Has the page paint completed?